# How to select date from a datepicker structure?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I have the following datepicker structure:

```
<div class="datepicker -bottom-left- -from-bottom- active" style="left: 43px; top: 568px;">
   <i class="datepicker--pointer"></i>
   <nav class="datepicker--nav">
      <div class="datepicker--nav-action" data-action="prev">
         <svg>
            <path d="M 17,12 l -5,5 l 5,5"></path>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="datepicker--nav-title">Agosto, <i>2023</i></div>
      <div class="datepicker--nav-action" data-action="next">
         <svg>
            <path d="M 14,12 l 5,5 l -5,5"></path>
         </svg>
      </div>
   </nav>
   <div class="datepicker--content">
      <div class="datepicker--days datepicker--body active">
         <div class="datepicker--days-names">
            <div class="datepicker--day-name -weekend-">Do</div>
            <div class="datepicker--day-name">Se</div>
            <div class="datepicker--day-name">Te</div>
            <div class="datepicker--day-name">Qu</div>
            <div class="datepicker--day-name">Qu</div>
            <div class="datepicker--day-name">Se</div>
            <div class="datepicker--day-name -weekend-">Sa</div>
         </div>
         <div class="datepicker--cells datepicker--cells-days">
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend- -other-month-" data-date="30" data-month="6" data-year="2023">30</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -other-month-" data-date="31" data-month="6" data-year="2023">31</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="1" data-month="7" data-year="2023">1</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="2" data-month="7" data-year="2023">2</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -current-" data-date="3" data-month="7" data-year="2023">3</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="4" data-month="7" data-year="2023">4</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend-" data-date="5" data-month="7" data-year="2023">5</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend-" data-date="6" data-month="7" data-year="2023">6</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="7" data-month="7" data-year="2023">7</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="8" data-month="7" data-year="2023">8</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="9" data-month="7" data-year="2023">9</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="10" data-month="7" data-year="2023">10</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="11" data-month="7" data-year="2023">11</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend-" data-date="12" data-month="7" data-year="2023">12</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend-" data-date="13" data-month="7" data-year="2023">13</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="14" data-month="7" data-year="2023">14</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="15" data-month="7" data-year="2023">15</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="16" data-month="7" data-year="2023">16</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="17" data-month="7" data-year="2023">17</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="18" data-month="7" data-year="2023">18</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend-" data-date="19" data-month="7" data-year="2023">19</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend-" data-date="20" data-month="7" data-year="2023">20</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="21" data-month="7" data-year="2023">21</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="22" data-month="7" data-year="2023">22</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="23" data-month="7" data-year="2023">23</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="24" data-month="7" data-year="2023">24</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="25" data-month="7" data-year="2023">25</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend-" data-date="26" data-month="7" data-year="2023">26</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend-" data-date="27" data-month="7" data-year="2023">27</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="28" data-month="7" data-year="2023">28</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="29" data-month="7" data-year="2023">29</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="30" data-month="7" data-year="2023">30</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="31" data-month="7" data-year="2023">31</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -other-month-" data-date="1" data-month="8" data-year="2023">1</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend- -other-month-" data-date="2" data-month="8" data-year="2023">2</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="datepicker--months datepicker--body">
         <div class="datepicker--cells datepicker--cells-months">
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="0">Jan</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="1">Fev</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="2">Mar</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="3">Abr</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="4">Mai</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="5">Jun</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="6">Jul</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month -current-" data-month="7">Ago</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="8">Set</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="9">Out</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="10">Nov</div>
            <div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-month" data-month="11">Dez</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to choose automatically a date from this structure using Selenium or another way. But how can I do it? The date it is not a string, but it is separated by date, month and year inside a div.

For example: I want to select 01/08/2023. I know it is this element:

```
<div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day" data-date="1" data-month="8" data-year="2023">1</div>
```

But the question is: How can I select it correctly?

Already tried find_element, but without success.

Comment: Is it a public URL so we can access?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), but you can adapt the code for Selenium also.

###### Code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

looking_for = "30/6/2023"

for tag in soup.find_all(class_="datepicker--cell-day"):
    data = "/".join([tag["data-date"], tag["data-month"], tag["data-year"]])
    if data == looking_for:
        print(tag) # or tag.text if you want the text inside the tag
        break
```

Prints:

```html
<div class="datepicker--cell datepicker--cell-day -weekend- -other-month-" data-date="30" data-month="6" data-year="2023">30</div>
```

---

###### Explanation

- You look for an HTML class using `.find_all()`.
- The for loop iterates through all the HTML elements with the class `"datepicker--cell-day"`,
- `data = "/".join([tag["data-date"], tag["data-month"], tag["data-year"]])`: For each tag, it extracts the date, month, and year from the `data-date`, `data-month`, and `data-year` attributes of the tag, and join them with '/' to form a string in the format "day/month/year".